# Swift 3 : Swipe Action appears, but doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using tableView `editActionsForRowAt` function for swipe action. It appears, but action doesn't work. When I click the swipe action, my functions have to work, but they don't. Normally, `getOnay` and `loadOnaylar` are working in the other `viewController`, but not here.

Here is my code :

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let onay = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Onay") { action, index in
// these are my functions. but they don't work here.
            self.getOnay(id: self.onayCode.id, status: "ok")
            self.loadOnaylar(userID: self.onayCode.userId, code: self.onayCode.systemCode)
            self.alertView(title: "Onaylandı!", message: "Görev onaylandı.")


        }
        onay.backgroundColor = .green

        let ret = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Ret") { action, index in
            self.getOnay(id: self.onayCode.id, status: "cancel")
            self.loadOnaylar(userID: self.onayCode.userId, code: self.onayCode.systemCode)
            self.alertView(title: "Ret edildi!", message: "Görev ret edildi.")

        }
        ret.backgroundColor = .red
        //favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "redicon")!)



        return [ret, onay]
    }
```

Comment: Is the UITableViewRowAction being called? Use print() to check if the code block is executed.

Comment: yeah, alertView works, but the others don't

Comment: https://pastebin.com/75uLMGgq It seems to be working fine in my project. I would suggest trying to create/call a different method and check if that does works.

Comment: okay, I found the problem. the problem is, I can't get the row's items. how can i get them when i use swipe action?

Comment: Use the following line of code: "let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: editActionsForRowAt)". place it above the definition of your first action.

Comment: but I can't see the index number here. I also need an index number, bec every cell has a unique id in my class.

Comment: The indexPath has an index number by just using the .row variable: "indexPath.row" there is your index number.

Comment: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row I tried this one, but it gets nil.

Comment: Yes because did not select a row you swiped a row. Just use this: "editActionsForRowAt.row" in the method where you define your swipe actions. If that doesn't work edit your post with an updated version of your current code.

Comment: editActionsForRowAt.row works perfectly! thanks.

Comment: Please summarize and answer your own question so it can be closed. Good luck!

Comment: okay. I answered my question. thanks for your advices. it really worked!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that self.onayCode.id was nil in the getOnay function. On the other hand, I wanted to get indexPath when I swipe the table row cell.

I used `editActionsForRowAt.row` for getting the index. Then I got my row's id.

Here is my working code :

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let onay = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Onay") { action, index in
            let ip = editActionsForRowAt.row
            let taskInfo:Task = self.onayArray[ip]

            self.getOnay(id: taskInfo.id, status: "ok")

            print(taskInfo.id,"< id bu")
            self.loadOnaylar(userID: taskInfo.userId, code: self.onayCode.systemCode)
            self.alertView(title: "Onaylandı!", message: "Görev onaylandı.")


        }
        onay.backgroundColor = .green

    return [onay]

}
```